# Extracting the width of a QMenu ? Weird Issue

Tags: c++, qt

In my windows application my QMenu pops up from a certain corner of QWidget. In order to calculate the exact position from where the QMenu pops up I use the following statement

```
QPoint p = btn->mapToGlobal(QPoint(0,0));

//Now get the size of the menu
int widthmnu =mnu->geometry().width();

//Create new Qpoint
int new_x =  p.x() - (widthmnu+5);
p.setX(new_x);

mnu->exec(p);
```

Now the problem is the very first time this method runs the result of `mnu->geometry().width()` is 680 (which is wrong and the menu pops up in the wrong place). Now if this method is called again the result of  mnu->geometry().width() is 140 which is correct. My question is why do I always get the wrong value the first time the menu starts. Is there a way for me to fix this ? I cant even think of a hack that would work for the first case.

**Update:**
I noticed that the value of width would only be correct if .exec() method is made.
So the first time the width is wrong and then exec() call is made. After that the correct value of width is there. I am still looking for a fix

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a relevant comment from the [documentation for QMenu::exec()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmenu.html#exec):

> When positioning a menu with exec() or popup(), bear in mind that you
>   cannot rely on the menu's current size(). For performance reasons, the
>   menu adapts its size only when necessary. So in many cases, the size
>   before and after the show is different. Instead, use sizeHint() which
>   calculates the proper size depending on the menu's current contents.